# route failureHandler is blocked in SmallRye Mutiny Vertx bindings

Tags: vert.x, reactive, smallrye

I tried to experience the SmallRye Mutiny Vertx bindings, the [complete example codes](https://github.com/hantsy/vertx-sandbox/tree/master/mutiny-spring-hibernate) can be found on my Github.

When assembling the routings like this.

```java
router.get("/posts/:id").produces("application/json")
            .handler(handlers::get);
            //.failureHandler(frc -> frc.response().setStatusCode(404).end());
```

The `failureHandler` will block the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that end returns a `Uni` object. You can think of it as a function. This function is lazy. What you want to do instead is *call* that function. This can be achieved by subscribing to it.

If you're not interested in processing the result of this `Uni`, you can use `endAndForget` instead of `end` which will call that function for you (subscribe to the `Uni`).

If you would like to do something with the result of the `Uni`, you can subscribe instead:

```java
.failureHandler(frc ->
  frc.response()
    .setStatusCode(404)
    .end()
    .subscribe().with(ignore -> System.out.println("failure handler is done"))
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Using a `endAndAwait` to replace `end`.